# Is there any function or algorithm which could map the labeled clusters into a space where all clusters are away from each other as far as possible?

Tags: classification, clustering, algorithms

Is there any function which could map the labeled clusters into a space where all clusters are away from each other as far as possible?
Now I have many labeled clusters, but they may be mixed in low dimension space. So I want to find a function or algorithm that could do this. I think the problem in this way:
 First, there should be some function or algorithm with parameters.
 Second, By learning from those labeled clusters, I could get the parameters of the mapping function or mapping algorithm. 
 Finally, I get the mapping method.
However, I have no idea about what kinds of function or algorithm is suitable for my problem. Can someone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: Since you have already identified (labeled) your clusters, this is not a clustering problem. Essentially you want to train a [classifier](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification), where each cluster is considered a separate class. For example [SVM](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/svm/info) is a "maximum margin classifier", which is essentially your goal.

Comment: It is  really similar to classification problem but not. Let me tell more about my purpose. When I get the specific mapping function or algorithm, I use it transform my test data. In the transformed test data set, I will do clustering.  The reason for not clustering on original test data set is that they may be mixed in a low dimension space and could be separate in high dimension space. Therefore, I need some good mapping method. The mapping method learned from current labeled clusters could be convincing.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute "clusters" by "classes" and you will find many projection techniques.

For example [Fisher's Linear Discriminant Analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) (the other LDA) tries to find the *linear* projection that best separates classes. And of course other approaches have been proposed since 1936.